# Button Object Access

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, get, set

I'm very rusty with my C# skills, but essentially I need to turn off a button I'm creating programmatically to "return" to the main menu. I can't access my button, what am I forgetting? This is the line causing issue : **ikr1.visible = false;**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Locker_Rental
{    
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public object ikr1 { get; private set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button4.Visible = false;
        Button lkr1 = new Button();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hide_buttons();
        build_LL1_Key_Lockers();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hide_buttons();
        build_LL1_Combo_Lockers();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hide_buttons();
        build_L2_Combo_Lockers();
    }

    private void hide_buttons()
    {
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = false;
    }

    private void show_buttons()
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
    }

    private void build_LL1_Key_Lockers()
    {
        button4.Visible = true;
        Button lkr1 = new Button();
        lkr1.Location = new Point(25, 25);
        lkr1.Text = "1";
        lkr1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        lkr1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
        Controls.Add(lkr1);

    }

    private void build_LL1_Combo_Lockers()
    {
        button4.Visible = true;
    }

    private void build_L2_Combo_Lockers()
    {
        button4.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button4.Visible = false;
        //turn off ikr1
        **ikr1.visible = false;**

        show_buttons();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: mmm declare your variable as a button

Comment: pick better names than ikr1 and lkr1 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are making reference to the **object ikr1**, not the Button *(because it doesn't even exist!)*. The button is beign instantiated in the internal methods, so you can't access from **private void button4_Click** method. You need to **declare** the button outside this methods and make the **instance** in your event method.

Try this:

```
namespace Locker_Rental
{    
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public object ikr1 { get; private set; }
        public Button myButton;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button4.Visible = false;
            myButton = new Button();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hide_buttons();
            build_LL1_Key_Lockers();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hide_buttons();
            build_LL1_Combo_Lockers();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hide_buttons();
            build_L2_Combo_Lockers();
        }

        private void hide_buttons()
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = false;
            button3.Visible = false;
        }

        private void show_buttons()
        {
            button1.Visible = true;
            button2.Visible = true;
            button3.Visible = true;
        }

        private void build_LL1_Key_Lockers()
        {
            button4.Visible = true;
            myButton = new Button();
            myButton.Location = new Point(25, 25);
            myButton.Text = "1";
            myButton.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            myButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
            Controls.Add(myButton);

        }

        private void build_LL1_Combo_Lockers()
        {
            button4.Visible = true;
        }

        private void build_L2_Combo_Lockers()
        {
            button4.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button4.Visible = false;
            //turn off ikr1
            myButton.Visible = false;

            show_buttons();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's okay, you can do it later. I think you can mark it as acceptable answer, in case it solved the problem @Trying2Code

Comment: Doesn't see visible as an extension of Button: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'visible' and no extension method 'visible' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Must be **Visible** not **visible**  @Trying2Code

Comment: Now it sees it but i have NullReferenceException was unhandled.

Comment: You added **myButton = new Button();** to public Form1() constructor? @Trying2Code

Comment: I did. Do I have to set visible to true before I can set it to false? Seems like the constructor would do that...